# Hard-coding values in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a DTO (or POCO class, uncertain what the correct term is) class (within Model) with the following values:

```
public class MainDTO
{
    public CustomerDTO[] customer { get; set; }
    public string itemPurchased { get; set; }
    public int staffId { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDTO
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string[] address { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling this in my MVC app after a REST webservice call which returns a Json with the values for the class stated above.

I want to hard-code these values in the controller so that I can test the view. However, I don't know how I can hard-code a value which is calling another class.

```
//Response variable below contains Json result of the web service call
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GETModel.MainDTO>(response); 

//Hard-coding values to test view
root.customer = ? //How can I hard-code this value?
root.itemPurchased = “Random Item”;
root.staffId = 2299;

return View(root);
```

How can I hard-code the "root.customer" variable? It contains an array and string variable.

Comment: Create a class instance, set its variables to the hard coded values you want, and serialize it - the opposite of what you're doing to deserialize..

Comment: `root.customer` is an array.  What do you want to set it to?  Just an empty array?  `new CustomerDTO[0]` ?

Comment: You can set it to an empty array, an array with hard-coded values, etc.  The choice is yours.  `root.customer = new CustomerDTO[0];` or `root.customer = new [] { new CustomerDTO() { name = "John Smith", address = new [] { "123 Main St", "Washington D.C" } };`

Comment: It's calling another class which has an array and a string. I want to sent values for both 'name' and 'address' in the CustomerDTO class called from root.customer variable.

Comment: I would also highly recommend looking through the C# style/naming conventions.  Lower case public property names are no bueno.

Comment: You can set your customer property this way dto.customer = new CustomerDTO[] { new CustomerDTO {name = "name" , address = new string[] {"address 1", "address 1"}}};

Answer (score 3):

Create a new instance of that class (or rather a new Array of that class instances) and populate it.

```
root.customer = new CustomerDTO[] 
{ 
    new CustomerDTO() 
    {
        name = "",
        address = new string[] 
        { 
            "value1", 
            "value2" 
        }
    }
};
```

Since it's a public class with public setters you can easily do that.

Comment: With type inference, you don't even need the `CustomerDTO` or `string` types before the brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not like hardcoding, you can do something like this.

```
    List<CustomerDTO> customers = new List<CustomerDTO>();

    var customer1 = new CustomerDTO();
    customer1.name = "xyz";
    customer1.address = new string[1];
    customer1.address[0] = "123, xyz st, city, state";

    var customer2 = new CustomerDTO();
    customer2.name = "abc";
    customer2.address = new string[1];
    customer2.address[0] = "123, abc st, city, state";

    customers.Add(customer1);
    customers.Add(customer2);

    //Hard-coding values to test view
    root.customer = customers.ToArray();
    root.itemPurchased = “Random Item”;
    root.staffId = 2299;

    return View(root);
```